# Can I import a SQL View from Server Explorer into my Model without having to write the class myself?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a **SQL View** in my server explorer and I need to add its class in my model. I am using the code-first approach. I cannot see an option in visual studio that allows me to add the view to the model. Do I have to type the class myself?

Comment: as you said. You are using `code-first`. if there is no code but a database that's something different

Comment: @FelixD. What would be the answer if it was database-first? Can you get data classes from server explorer anyway?

Comment: Your question can be rephrased to `can I reverse-engineer an existing database with EF code-first ?` and the answer is yes, with the proper tool

Comment: [Code First From database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database#3-reverse-engineer-model) is an option in Visual Studio's `Entity Data Model Wizard`. It allows you to select both tables and views for reverse engineering. This works only with EF 6+, not EF Core

Answer (score 1):

If you are using entity framework core there is the command

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables *insert your tables/views here* -OutputDir Models`

There is a detailed guide  [Getting started  existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

Hope it helps